# SQL: modifying query output subject to a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called HOTEL which stores the details of hotels. I also have a table called ROOM which stores the details of rooms in hotels (number of bedrooms, etc.)

I have the following code:

```
SELECT
    h.hotel_id,
    h.hotel_name,
    COUNT(r.room_no) || ' rooms total, ' 
        || SUM(CASE WHEN r.room_bedoorms > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        || ' have more than 2 bedrooms ' AS ACCOMODATION_AVAILABLE
FROM hotel h
INNER JOIN room r ON h.hotel_id = r.hotel_id
GROUP BY h.hotel_id, h.hotel_name;
```

The code works fine, and this is my output:

[image: Screen-Shot-2019-10-24-at-8-19-23-pm.png]

However I only want to display those hotels that have 1 or more rooms that have more than 2 bedrooms. In this case, I only want my output to display hotels 2 and 5.

Could somebody please point out what modification I need to make in my code to achieve this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`HAVING`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause

```
SELECT
    h.hotel_id,
    h.hotel_name,
    COUNT(r.room_no) || ' rooms total, ' 
        || SUM(CASE WHEN r.room_bedoorms > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        || ' have more than 2 bedrooms ' AS ACCOMODATION_AVAILABLE
FROM hotel h
INNER JOIN room r ON h.hotel_id = r.hotel_id
GROUP BY h.hotel_id, h.hotel_name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.room_bedoorms > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

use having

```
SELECT
    h.hotel_id,
    h.hotel_name,
    COUNT(r.room_no) || ' rooms total, ' 
        || SUM(CASE WHEN r.room_bedoorms > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        || ' have more than 2 bedrooms ' AS ACCOMODATION_AVAILABLE
FROM hotel h
INNER JOIN room r ON h.hotel_id = r.hotel_id
GROUP BY h.hotel_id, h.hotel_name
having SUM(CASE WHEN r.room_bedoorms > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>=2
and COUNT(r.room_no)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `having` clause.  One version uses conditional aggregation:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.room_bedrooms > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

However, I think it is simpler to write:

```
HAVING MAX(r.room_bedrooms) > 2
```